# ESP32 HCI command for setting BLE TX Power

Tags: arduino-nano, esp32

Does anyone know if there's an HCI command for setting the TX and the advertising power for BLE on an ESP32?

I have a Nano 33 IoT and a MKR 1010, and it has its power set annoyingly low for advertising and transmission.  The library that I'm using is [ArduinoBLE](https://github.com/arduino-libraries/ArduinoBLE), which uses HCI to communicate with the ESP32.

I believe that espressiv allows the power level to be set using their dev kit, and I know that other vendors (e.g., [TexasInstruments](http://dev.ti.com/tirex/content/simplelink_cc26x2_sdk_2_10_00_44/docs/ble5stack/vendor_specific_guide/BLE_Vendor_Specific_HCI_Guide/hci_interface.html)) provide extensions to HCI for setting power levels, but I haven't been able to find an HCI command for ESP32 anywhere.

Any ideas on other ways that I could do this other than HCI would be welcome too (e.g., other libraries for BLE that would work with the MKR and Nano series of boards, but would allow setting the power level for advertising and transmission.

Comment: Nano 33 BLE doesn't use ESP32. it has a nRF52. do you have Nano 33 IoT?

Comment: No, you're right!  I've got a bunch of these things sitting around... I have an IoT and also a MKR1010.  I'll update the post.

Comment: on Nano 33 IoT and MKR 1010 the esp32 is controlled by the firmware so if the firmware doesn't have the setting in API, then it is not available

Comment: So you're telling me the AndroidBLE library that I'm using, which uses HCI commands to control and interact with BLE subsystem is NOT talking directly to the ESP32?

Comment: it is/ the firmware does the setup() with esp_bt_controller SDK functions, but then the esp32 SDK listens for HCI commands on UART.

Comment: OK, so that's the point of my question.  I don't think that setting power level is a one time operation (at setup only). For example, their SDK allows you to set transmission power for each connection.  I just need to know the HCI command to set the advertising power level, and I can call it myself as an HCI command through the UART.  Maybe there isn't an HCI command for setting power levels.  I just can't find info on the list of HCI commands supported by the chip anywhere!